# Is $x$ a free variable in sentences like "$x\lt 7\Rightarrow x\lt 5$"?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Is $x$ a free variable in sentences like "$x\lt 7\Rightarrow x\lt 5$"? I consulted an advanced calculus book and it says that this is a false sentence, which indicates that $x$ is a bound variable.

However, $\Rightarrow$ is a logical operator which connects two "sentences" involving free varibales, namely $P(x): x\lt 7$ and $Q(x):x\lt 5$. The truth values of P(x) and Q(x) cannot be determined since $x$ is free there. If we take $x=1$, then $P(x)\Rightarrow Q(x)$ becomes $1\lt 7\Rightarrow 1\lt 5$, which is a true sentence. If we take $x=6$, then $P(x)\Rightarrow Q(x)$ becomes $6\lt 7\Rightarrow 6\lt 5$, which is a false sentence.

So I think the truth value of $x\lt 7\Rightarrow x\lt 5$ isn't determined either. In order to turn $x$ into a bound variable, we should instead say $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}, x\lt 7\Rightarrow x\lt 5$. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: When a variable is _bound_, it is _bound by some quantifier_. No quantifier, no bound variables. So $x$ is free in $x < 7 \rightarrow x < 5$.

Comment: Technically, `x<7` is an open formula rather than a sentence. Your calculus book may be trying to say that `x<7⇒x<5` is implicitly universally quantified, that is, to be understood as `∀x∈R(x<7⇒x<5)`.

Comment: I think you have a correct understanding, but usually from context you know if they mean "every x", and usually they do.  "Free variable" tends to only be something applied to sub expressions for the sake of things like substitutions, you usually don't ask about free variables in stand alone assertions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the context. If your statement here was a line in a formal proof, the $x$ would be a free variable in that statement since it is not quantified.

For readability in informal presentations such as found in most math textbooks, a universal quantifier is often assumed if there is no possibility of confusion. If the author was talking about a single value of $x$, he or she might say something like, "Let $x$ be a real number such that...".

Answer (score 0):

"$x<7\to x<5$" is not always TRUE. Because the logic behind it is $x<7$ implies $x\epsilon(-\infty,7)$ and $x<5$ implies $x\epsilon(-\infty,5)$ . Now according to your question "$x<7\to x<5$" is not true because $x<7$ never implies that $x$ have to be always $<5$ . $x$ can be $>5$ . This implies $x\epsilon (5,7)$ . I think you have understood my point.